# Window Resizing and elements

Tags: html, css

For my website, as of now, I have all my elements within a container with a set width of 1250px. I've realized that if I try to resize it by increasing the width of the browser, all I see is extra white space, which I understand why is happening.

This is my next question: Is there any way to possibly make it so regardless of the width I specify in my HTML, if the user or anyone attempts to resize it (make it more than the specified width) I want to make it so the elements just stretch out and there is no white space shown.

Let me know if any more clarification is needed. THanks!

Comment: Yes. There are many, many ways to achieve this.  Search for "responsive" or "fluid". As it stands this question is way too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the container to a relative size, such as 100%:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will scale the containers width based on its parent (the browser window).

Comment: I thought of that too but the problem with that is that, I have 5 images in a div and making the width 100% messes the images completely if I decrease the window size. All of them go on the next line and I don't want that. If there's a way to stop the images from doing that, and have width 100% then it would be something I would consider. Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the bootstrap grid system have a look on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
The grid system will make stretch the div elements based on the browser/ window size by using media queries